# PHP form, reset button, modify button logic

Tags: php, html, forms, reset

Having some trouble with my PHP form.

I have a simple form which pretty much does:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
} elseif (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
} else {
}
```

It is pretty much a form with a submit, then confirmation screen (with a modify button which goes back to previous screen). To implement the modify button, I used a input type submit button. On form submits, the form would just go back to itself. Since it was not a name = "submit" or "confirm" (modify button name is "modify"), it would go into the else and I used $_POST array to fill in the form with what data it had before by doing something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['event_name'])) {
        $event_name = $_POST['event_name'];
}
else {
        $event_name = "";
}
```

And then the different form fields would use $event_name or its respective var to fill in the default value.

But by doing this, I broke my form's reset button (input type = "reset") which would have cleared all the fields in the form, which it does not do so after Modify is pressed. Anyone know of a better way I can fix this? I currently just have my reset button refresh the page right now, which isn't so ideal.

I also have an issue where I get a couple corrupted characters that appear on screen when I use the Modify button. Any place I should start looking for why they appear? A picture of said problem: [image: http://puu.sh/7ptan.png]

and

[image]

Comment: You can use javascript to have the Reset button clear all the fields.

Comment: @Barmar does this not do the same thing as the Reset button? Pardon some of the obvious statements I will make, but it seems that I need to make my Reset button also clear all my variables because my all my fields values are set to a variable. How could I go about to making my reset button reset my various vars as well as prompting a reset? I am quite new at this.

Comment: The reset button just needs to clear all the form fields, it doesn't need to clear PHP variables because PHP isn't running when the user is filling out the form.

Comment: @Barmar the variables would have a play into this because of how I created my fields "<input type='text' size='30' name='who' value='$who'>". Is there a way I can simply set all the vars to "" and then reset using just what is available to me through php/javascript

Comment: But those variables are irrelevant by the time the user is working with the form. PHP is on the server, not the client. Every time the user submits the form, they get set from `$_POST`, then all variables go away when the PHP script finishes.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is simply add the $_POST into a Database (MySQL) (just make sure to sanitize it all). If the user wants to edit a post they could simply just add an edit button which loads, say a textarea, with the value of that post (the one stored inside the database).

Something along the lines of the following... **Example code**

```
 define("DB_TYPE", "mysql");
 define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
 define("DB_NAME", "form_posts");
 define("DB_USER", "user");
 define("DB_PASS", "password");
 private $db_connection = null;
 private function createDatabaseConnection(){
        try {        
            $this->db_connection = new PDO(DB_TYPE.':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->feedback = "PDO database connection problem: " . $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->feedback = "General problem: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
     return false;
}
private function accessDB($sql){
         $this->createDatabaseConnection();
         $query = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
        // bind the value you wish to access to the corresponding :value
         if(isset($_POST['value'])){
             $query->bindValue(':value',$_POST['value']);
         }
        $query->execute();
        $result_row = $query->fetchAll() ; 
     return $result_row;  
}
public function getPostVal(){
     $FormPost = htmlentities($_POST['ForumPost'], ENT_QUOTES);

     $result_row = $this->accessDB("SELECT count(ForumPost) FROM users WHERE ForumPost = {$ForumPost} LIMIT 1");
     return array_map(function($entry) { return $entry['account_ID']; }, $result_row);
}
public function setPostVal($val){
     $this->createDatabaseConnection();

     $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FormPost, post_id)
                VALUES(:FormPost, :post_id)'";
     $query = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
     $isSuccess = $query->execute();
     if($isSuccess){
          echo 'success!';
     } else { echo 'the action failed';}
}
```

have `<?=getPostVal(); ?>` inside a textarea or something then have `setPostVal($val)` submit the data

From here you can just adjust the values needed to make the proper post. Maybe add an edit button or what have you.